# How to stop normal map from different seperate meshes from overlapping when baking?

Tags: normal-map

I'm making a game asset gun which are made of a number of seperate meshes so I baked the normal map piece by piece. There are some spaces between the islands and yet they still overlap, does this has something to do with margin?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try reducing margin in the bake settings